# Selecting JSON array with conditions in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a text file which displays all the records in datatables correctly but I want to display only the records with "ram".  For example:

```
{ "aaData": [
["ram","india"],
["siva","india"],
["mani","india"],
["ram","india"],
["ram","india"]
] }
```

I am using PHP and Symfony1.3.  Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$json_str = '{ "aaData": [
["ram","india"],
["siva","india"],
["mani","india"],
["ram","india"],
["ram","india"]
] }
';
$array = json_decode($json_str, true); 
$entries_with_ram = array();
foreach($array['aaData']  as $entry)
    if($entry[0] == "ram")
        $entries_with_ram[] = $entry;

print_r($entries_with_ram);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$array = json_decode($json_str, true); // convert json to array
print_r($array['ram']); // display items with ram key
```

Comment: help me how to use iniside this,'sAjaxSource':'testing.txt'